# django remove tags from string python

Tags: python, django, html-parser

I want to remove all html tags  except  from my string with python
i use this:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser   

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

But this remove all my html tags.

Comment: How refreshing, I came in expecting a RegEx. Nice to be surprised.

Comment: [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/) can do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to strip html tags, but to keep some specific ones ?
If that's the case - then just keep monitoring the start/end tags, and process them if needed. Example:

```
MY_TAGS = ["tag1", "tag2"]

MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag in MY_TAGS:
            self.fed.append("<%s>" % tag) # tag is only string, no < or >.
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag in MY_TAGS:
            self.fed.append("</%s>" % tag)
```